# Looking information returned from whois

Tags: whois, penetration-testing

```
msf > whois 75.118.185.142 [*] exec: whois 75.118.185.142 WideOpenWest Finance LLC WIDEOPENWEST (NET-75-118-0-0-1)
75.118.0.0 - 75.118.255.255 WIDEOPENWEST OHIO WOW-CL11-1-184-118-75 (NET-75-118-184-0-1)
75.118.184.0 - 75.118.191.255
```

> We see from the whois lookup and a quick search that this IP
>   (WIDEOPENWEST) appears to be a legitimate service provider. While the
>   actual subnet range isn’t specifically registered to secmaniac.net or
>   secmaniac.com, we can tell that this site appears to be hosted inside
>   the author’s home, because the IP block appears to be part of a
>   residential range.

*source: Metasploit-The Penetration Testers Guide*

How can the author predict that, this site appears to be hosted inside  the authors' home? Please explain it in layman terms.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of services that can help you understand what type of IP address this is in layman's terms. The one that I have used most is [ip2location](https://www.ip2location.com/demo/75.118.185.142).

When checking for the IP address in your post it has the Usage Type '(ISP) Fixed Line ISP' which means that this is an IP address assigned by an ISP to residential customers. You can see the different types of usage [here](https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/what-is-usage-type/).